# Unicode characters printed as escape sequences inside python object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.13. My python script generates a dictionary, which contains Hebrew.

The code is as follows,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

val = "אבג".decode('utf-8')
print val
dict = {
        'attributes' : {
        'OBJECTID_1' : 1,
        'LOCID' : val
         }
}
print dict
```

The results are as follows,

```
אבג
{'attributes': {'LOCID': u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2', 'OBJECTID_1': 1}}
```

The first result shows as expected, since we use 'print'. However, in the dictionary I created, the Hebrew shows as unicode.

Is there anyway to display actual Hebrew in my dictionary? Or is this expected?

Thanks

Comment: That's okay. What you're doing is printing the `repr` of the string. You can confirm this is so:

Comment: A simple fix would be switching to Python 3 while it's not too late.

Comment: `>>> val ;
u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2' ;
>>> print val ;
אבג`

Comment: Ya it works fine on python 3. I will have to take a look on python 2 to see whats going on here.

Comment: Look at `print dict['LOCID']`.

Comment: also, `dict` is a reserved keyword in `python`, it's not recomanded to use it as an identifier

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ: Technically, `dict` is neither reserved nor a keyword, it's a builtin.  You still shouldn't redefine it, though.

Comment: @jwodder [you're right](https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/keywords.html)

Comment: @GhilasBELHADJ why are you linking to ancient docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python2, when you print out a list, you end up printing the `repr` of the contents of that list.

In python3, a string's `repr` is the same as its `str` return value. You can observe this below:

Python2

```
>>> val = "אבג".decode('utf-8')
>>> val         # displays repr value
u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2'
>>> print val   # displays str value
אבג
```

And, as mentioned,

```
>>> print [val]
[u'\u05d0\u05d1\u05d2']
```

Constrasting with python3, `str` objects do not have a `decode` function - they are already decoded.

```
>>> val = "אבג"
>>> val
'אבג'
>>> print(val)
אבג
>>> print([val])
['אבג']
```

You can see this is why it works now.

For your problem, if you want to view the character as it is when you print the dict, you can do this:

```
print dict['LOCID']
```

Side note, do not use `dict` to name variables since it shadows the very important builtin class you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That makes sense. I think I will just go head and use python 3.